# Symfony 2: Download multiple images files in a Zip one

Tags: php, symfony, request, zip

I'd like download multiple files in a zip but it doesn't work: the downloaded zip folder is still empty and is like opt/lampp/htdocs/MYPROJECT/... which one I'd like simple like /filename.zip

my controller, I just get all the file names from the DB and concatenate them with the directory name where they are physically saved:

```
$response = new Response();
    // Get the entity manager
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    //Collect all the result from the database and zip all the files related
    $files = $em->getRepository('IballotCmsBundle:Result')->findAll();

    $directory = __DIR__.'/../../../../web/uploads/pinkSheet';
    //$directory = __DIR__.'/../temp/de.jpg';

    $filename = 'all.zip';
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE);

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $zip->addFile($directory.'/'.$file->getImage());
    }

    $zip->close();

    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'private');
    $response->headers->set('Content-type', mime_content_type($filename));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '"');
    $response->headers->set('Content-length', filesize($filename));

    // Send headers before outputting anything
    $response->sendHeaders();

    $response->setContent(readfile($filename));

    return $response;
```

Comment: what say error.log, and try catching error by `$res = $zip->open($filename,ZipArchive::CREATE); var_dump($res);die;`

Comment: the above code return  true

Comment: Ok. You check php error log?

Comment: sorry : where does the log file is located ? for I've never try to check it before

Comment: You use apache2 server?

Comment: greate. log file location in /var/log/apache2/your_host.error.log. You can look path in you virtualhost configuration. for read you can use `tailf -100 /var/log/apache2/your_host.error.log` in you console

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with this line of code:

```
$filename = 'all.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE);
```

You are trying to create a zip file called `all.zip` but you haven't specified the actual path. `$filename` should probably be something like this:

```
$filename = '/absolute/path/to/all.zip'
```

As for the structure of the zip file you'll need to read the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php#refsect1-ziparchive.addfile-examples) which has a great example:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('test.zip') === TRUE) {
    $zip->addFile('/path/to/index.txt', 'newname.txt');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

This will add the `/path/to/index.txt` file to the `test.zip` with the name `newname.txt` instead of `/path/to/index.txt`. You can use the second argument to control the directory (have a look at the comments in the docs for more info)

Comment: I try it but does not work: $zip->addFile($directory.'/'.$item->getImage(), 'newname.txt');

Comment: Could you please clarify if your zip file is even being created and if so, is it stored in the right path?

Comment: the file is not created allthough a zip file is created I meant: the zip file is not valid